# Calculation of $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+e^{nx}}e^{-x^2/n} $ on $\mathbb{R}^-$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I would intuitively suggest that it is something like:

$1$ for $x<0$ and $0.5$ for $x=0$, what do you think?

Comment: "what do you think?" That you use the word "intuitively" in a rather non standard way.

Comment: Agreed.  And $0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: Intuition apart, do you have a proof? Also, please reason out as much as you can, I am sure you can express your intuition in mathematical terms, like providing inequalities/asymptotics you expect to be true.

Comment: The reason why I asked was, because I don't know a technique how to solve for the $\liminf$, I just tried something and would appreciate any feedback: The case $x=0$ holds obviously. Let $x<0$. Method: Fix some $m$ -> Derive $inf_{k\geq m}$ (which will depend on m, not k) -> Derive $\sup_m$. Following this idea one finds $\inf_{k\geq m} f_k(x) = f_m(x)$. And $sup_m f_m(x) = 1$. One uses the monotonicity of $e$, the value $e^0 = 1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{nx} = 0$ for $x<0$.